# How pass and parse json to spring boot standalone application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, string-externalization

For example:

```
java -jar mySpringApplication --myJsonParameter="{\"myKey\":\"myValue\"}"
```

This should be resolved like that:

```
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    //or @Value("myJsonParameter") ? 
    private MyInputDto myInputDto;
}

public class MyInputDto {
    private String myKey;
}
```

The idea is to pass named parameter from command line (and following spring externalization practics) but inject Typed value parsed from json, not string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using property `spring.application.json` and annotate your `MyInputDto` as `@org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties`.

Start your application like this:

```
java -Dspring.application.json='{"myKey":"myValue"}' -jar mySpringApplication.jar
```

Implementing your service:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyInputDto.class)
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyInputDto myInputDto;

    // use myInputDto.getMyKey();

}

@ConfigurationProperties
public class MyInputDto {
    private String myKey;

    public String getMyKey() { return this.myKey; }

    public void setMyKey(String myKey) { this.myKey = myKey; }
}
```

See [Spring external configuration documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for more information.